# What is the meaning of `DeviceTime` in Windows event log event "6" messages

Tags: windows, event-log

Examining some interesting event happening on Windows 10, I read the Window events event log.
I saw some date-like strings (e.g.: `2080-03-16T14:57:52`) that made me wonder (the text message in German was "**Der Dateisystemfilter "wcifs" (10.0, ‎2080‎-‎03‎-‎16T14:57:52.000000000Z) wurde erfolgreich geladen und im Filter-Manager registriert.**"):
First I thought it may be the driver's build date, but then either the encoding must be severely wrong, or the date of the build machine must have been years in the future.

Here are just two examples from the event log in XML representation:

```xml
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-FilterManager" Guid="{f3c5e28e-63f6-49c7-a204-e48a1bc4b09d}" />
    <EventID>6</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-09-05T18:22:10.5031076Z" />
    <EventRecordID>23122</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="144" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>I74X4W7</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="FinalStatus">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceVersionMajor">10</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceVersionMinor">0</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceNameLength">5</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceName">wcifs</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceTime">2080-03-16T14:57:52.0000000Z</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

```xml
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-FilterManager" Guid="{f3c5e28e-63f6-49c7-a204-e48a1bc4b09d}" />
    <EventID>6</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-09-05T18:22:10.5201158Z" />
    <EventRecordID>23124</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="272" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>I74X4W7</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="FinalStatus">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceVersionMajor">10</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceVersionMinor">0</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceNameLength">6</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceName">CldFlt</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceTime">2098-12-15T18:56:43.0000000Z</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

So what do those `DeviceTime` strings mean actually?

Comment: Does https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180103-00/?p=97705 answer the question?

Comment: Reading "One of the fields in the Portable Executable (PE) header is called TimeDateStamp. It’s a 32-bit value representing the time the file was created, in the form of seconds since January 1, 1970 UTC." can you explain how `DeviceTime` is related to `TimeDateStamp`, and why it seems to contain nonsense values? Do they deliberately fill it with random bits while still outputting them as date? If, so they are clearly operating outside the [Ballmer Peak](https://xkcd.com/323/) IMHO.

Comment: Have you read the rest of that post beyond the 1st paragraph?

Comment: Maybe be more specific. I'd say: No, it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: The DeviceTime in the event data is not related to the
system time.
It's whatever the minifilter driver chose to put into it, which
probably translates into some binary data that has meaning to the
developer that wrote that driver.

I have checked on my computer, and I have exactly the same
event messages from `wcifs.sys` and `CldFlt.sys`, with exactly
the same bogus DeviceTime values:

[image]
[image]

I advise to ignore these values. Only the developer can explain them
(I hope he can...).